# Food Similarities

Tags: word-property

You are going to a food party on a small deserted island. The host asks that you bring food but first check with them about if it can be brought or not.

Some other people have already gotten accepted for:

- 12 slices of bread
- 18 pounds of cooked ravioli

To determine their criteria, you asked them a variety of questions:

- 1 block of lead - Not Allowed
- 2 zucchini - Allowed
- 12 blades of grass - Allowed
- 32 potatoes - Not Allowed
- 7 apples - Allowed
- 8 blueberries - Not Allowed
- 10 bananas - Allowed

What is their criteria for what to allow?

Hints:

> - 12 brain - Probably Not allowed
> - 12 pieces of pizza - Allowed
> - 12 pieces of metal - Not allowed

Hint #2:

> Re-read the first sentence

Comment: Is it a coincidence that food having $5$ letters is allowed in lots of $12$?

Comment: @Azync Hint: You may ask about 3 items and I will say whether they are allowed or not. Also notice how grass is "Allowed but be careful"

Comment: Are 12 brain allowed?

Comment: 12 blanki of blank

Comment: Does it not existing matter? If so, 12 pieces of pizza

Comment: Am I allowed to bring 12 pieces of pizza?

Comment: Meta-puzzle - Why was the grass "allowed but be careful" edited, especially after @pfg specifically pointed it out in a comment?

Comment: @Selvek sorry about that, talking to someone else I realised it should clearly be allowed.

Comment: 12 pieces of metal?

Comment: @Azync you could not bring 12 pieces of metal. 3/3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the criteria is:

> Items that float. The amount does not matter.

Reasoning:

> Lead, potatoes, ripe blueberries, and metal all sink in water. I couldn't find a consensus on whether brains float in water hence the "probably not allowed". Cooked Ravioli, apples, bread, zucchini, grass, Bananas, and pizza should all float. Regarding the second hint, you are going to a deserted island, so you probably want things that can easily float.

Answer (score 3):

> even amounts of odd-letter food or odd amounts of even letter food

Comment: It doesn't work for the '2 zucchini' and also doesn't explain the allowed/not allowed

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the numbers and such are just to distract the reader. Based on that, I have made a possible guess.

> The criteria for what they allow is based on how many people will eat a certain item. For example, nobody will eat a block of lead, but some people will not be able to eat enough blueberries since there are only 8. Similarly, 32 potatoes may be seen as way too much for a few people. This answer is probably wrong, but it is my best shot.

The conclusions I derived from the given hints:

> This is not related to letters. 12 pieces of pizza and 12 pieces of metal have the same amount of letters overall, but metal is not allowed which troubles me.

Comment: How many blades of grass is it reasonable to expect people to eat?

Answer (score 0):

I would not be posting this answer had it not been for hint 2, but here it goes

> There is no such thing as a food party on a deserted island. The entire riddle is based on a false premise so there is no host, and no criteria.