# The Knights' Gift

Tags: story, word-property

This puzzle is loosely inspired by [Food Similarities](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62816/food-similarities).

---

I'd like to begin, if I may, with **1 anecdote**.  This story was written on *2 scrolls* more than *900 years* ago, and goes as follows -

Once there were *2 knights*, who had been *4 fortnights* on the road.  Fatigued, they came at last to a crossroads, where the road split to **2 towns**.  Said one man to the other, "let us find an inn to rest *1 night* - I'm hungry enough to eat **9 dinners**!

They turned left down the path and arrived shortly at a small town, no more than **3 hectares** in size.  They quickly sought out the inn and paid **10 cents** for *2 meat pies*.  No sooner had they begun eating than a gathering of **5 farmwives** entered, speaking frantically amongst themselves.  Approaching, the travelers were able to make out a few of the words:

"... but what CAN we do against a pack of **12 timberwolves**?
"... we have but *4 warriors* between us and the nearby town, and those poorly armed..."
"... we must do something!  Since my son barely escaped them *11 evenings* ago, he's had **8 nightmares**!"

At this point the travelers felt compelled to speak.  "We are armored knights, and volunteer to help".

The next morning, the knights ventured out into the wild and within but *4 hours*, they had driven the wolves far afield.  Upon returning, a steward approached them.

"The Lord of this town offers his thanks, and grants **1 souvenir**, a gift of your choosing."
"We are glad to have been of help.  Might we perhaps have *2 horses* to speed our travels?"
To which the steward replied, "I am sorry, but for such a bold deed, my lord requires that you be granted bold gifts"

The knights were briefly puzzled, but shortly one lit up, saying, "Ah ha!  I know a few things we might ask for, and why!  It's quite simple, rea...

> (the rest of the manuscript is worn and unintelligible)

---

Next Puzzle: [The Knights and the Hounds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63437/the-knights-and-the-hounds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could ask for **1000 enormous staghounds**

> enormous staghounds contains all the letters necessary for the words **one thousand**

or maybe:

> **1 throne**, since only 1 souvenir was granted?

Comment: Incredibly close, but your request for 1000 staghounds has been denied.

Comment: Although it sounds like quite the dog party :)

Comment: I was so sure of that answer :(

Comment: It's really a technicality for the staghounds...  1 throne is correct.

Comment: Is this answer only wrong because 1000 would be read as "one thousand" or "a thousand" but "staghounds" cannot account for the initial "a" or "one"?

Comment: @Riley Yes (also, be careful of spoilers in comments)

Comment: 10 planets. But is it a bold request or just a stupid one?

Comment: @PL457 That's definitely a bold request.  Although maybe a little ambitious for what this town can produce :)

Comment: @LeeLeon I'd like to accept your answer since you were obviously the first to solve the puzzle,  it just needs a minor edit so the main answer is technically valid - ornery staghounds perhaps?

Comment: @Selvek - ok, how is the answer now?

Comment: Perfect!  Good job!

Answer (score 0):

The steward said:

> "I am sorry, but for such a bold deed, my lord requires that you be granted **bold** gifts"

So the *few things* are:

> **1 anecdote**, which shall be written and passed down. For **souvenir**.
>  **2 towns**, one for each knight. Each town's size is **3 hectares**. And **5 farmwives** to attend the towns.
>  **9 dinners**, for one of the knight since he's probably still hungry. And **10 cents** for another meat pies because, why not?
>  The carcasses of the **12 timberwolves**, to strike **nightmares** to other timberwolves. Not necessarily must be exactly **8** though.

Comment: The gift must follow the bold patterns where the number _is_ related to the noun. The number of nightmares _must_ then be 8. See [Lee Leon's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62869/32339).

Comment: @xhienne: Thanks for taking time to guide me. I was merely taking a guess to the answer "literally". I have seen Lee Leon's answer, but I still don't get it though.

Comment: @xhienne: I see it now, thank you for your kind explanation. Btw, to avoid spoiler, perhaps you could use the caesar's chiper, the one that uses shifting technique. I have seen some people use it for might-be-spoilers, rot13(yvxr guvf sbe rknzcyr).

Comment: You're welcome. Since you are a newcomer, I was not sure you would understand such an obfuscated text. Deleting and repeating my explanation in rot13, for anyone interested: Gur ybtvp vf gung gur abhaf va obyq (naq guhf gur tvsg lbh zhfg nfx) zhfg pbagnva rabhtu yrggref gb jevgr gur ahzore orsber gurz (1 gueBAR, 2 GBJaf, rgp).

Comment: @xhienne: Indeed, I was kind of confused at what looks like garbled texts at first time. A quick googling was thankfully what I need. I thank you for your kind consideration.